# Atributos HTML em linhas do webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

É possível incluir o atributo `data-id-tarefa="@item.id"` dentro de cada TR usando o WebGrid? Consigo incluir pelo JavaScript o atributo, mas todas as TRs me retornam o mesmo valor do id dentro do atributo e o que preciso é o valor de cada uma, como se estivesse fazendo pelo `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> É possível incluir o atributo data-id-tarefa="@item.id" dentro de cada TR usando o WebGrid?

Não. [`WebGridRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgridrow(v=vs.111).aspx) não possui métodos para trabalhar com campos `data-`.

Prefira usar uma `<table>` normal dentro do `@foreach`.

Comment: infelizmente foi o que acabei fazendo, junto com os filtros da tabela todos na mão. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @JoséSeraphim Procure não deixar a resposta aberta. [Veja aqui como usar o site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Qualquer coisa, só perguntar novamente.

Comment: pode me orientar a fazer isso?

Comment: Há um ícone em forma de "V" na contagem de votos de cada resposta. É só clicar nele para aceitar a resposta. Adicionalmente, você pode votar a favor da resposta clicando no ícone de seta para cima.

Comment: Putz, não imaginava que ali era um botão. Muito obrigado. Infelizmente meu voto não vai contar devida à minha baixa pontuação